# Create Request Response XML from WSDL

Tags: java, maven

I follwed the src given by tom.bujok, I created a Java project in eclipse

[how to generate a SOAP message with a fully populated request from WSDL without code gen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487699/how-to-generate-a-soap-message-with-a-fully-populated-request-from-wsdl-without)

I'm getting:

```
Resource [/xsds/xop.xsd] loading failed exception.
```

I'm not using this project as Maven, I added src of the following to my Java project:

```
Soap-builder
soap-common
soap-legacy
```

And I have added a few jars, as its can not be resolved.

```
com.google.guava_1.6.0.jar
common-lang3.jar
commons-io-2.2.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
soap-xmlbeans-1.2.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
xmlbeans.jar
xmlunit.jar
```

I want this src as Java project. I dont know what I missed.

Src downloaded from https://github.com/reficio/soap-ws

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have to copy and paste this package to my src folder

```
xsds
```

Problem resolved.